# How do I handle loops in my Google Sheets Script so that multiple (but not all) scripts run with one command?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**My sheet is structured as follows:**

1) A dropdown menu is triggered and opens when sheet is opened.
2) The dropdown menu has three options:

- Search.
- Run.
- Upload.

**SEARCH** opens a dialogue box that asks for a name and case number which are in turn placed in designated cells in my Google Sheet.

**RUN** searches my Gmail, Google documents, and Google calendars for results that match the search criteria.

**UPLOAD** creates calendar entries based on the results from RUN.

**My goal**

- I want to have those scripts associated with *RUN* also operate with *SEARCH*.
- I want the script to automatically search my Gmail, documents, and calendars for results that match the search criteria when I click *SEARCH* and enter search terms in the dialogue boxes without then also having to click *RUN* from the dropdown menu.
- I want *showPrompt* to also run *saveEmails* but **NOT** *eventcreator1*.
- I then want to rename *RUN* to *RE-RUN* so that it still does what it does (runs *saveEmails* but **NOT** *eventcreator1*) **without** having to re-enter search terms unless I'm searching for a new case.

I have tried repeatedly to delete or reorder my loops to no avail. I just can't get it right.
This is current code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('WAYNE+')
       .addItem('Search', 'showPrompt')
    .addItem('RUN↓', 'saveEmails')
    .addItem('Upload Time↑', 'eventcreator1')
       .addSeparator()
       .addToUi();
}
 function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Welcome',
      'ENTER CASE#:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var result1 = ui.prompt(
      'Welcome',
      'ENTER Client Name [First Last]:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
   var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var button1 = result1.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var text1 = result1.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh0 = sheet1.getSheets()[0];
  var sh1 = sheet1.getSheets()[1];
   var datePlace = sh1.getRange("B3");
   datePlace.setValue(text); 

    if (button1 == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh0 = sheet1.getSheets()[0];
  var sh1 = sheet1.getSheets()[1];
   var searchCriteria = sh1.getRange("B2");
   searchCriteria.setValue(text1); 
    }}}
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sh0 = sheet1.getSheets()[0];
  var sh1 = sheet1.getSheets()[1];
var sh2 = sheet1.getSheets()[2];
var sh3 = sheet1.getSheets()[3];
var sh4 = sheet1.getSheets()[4];
var sh5 = sheet1.getSheets()[5];
var sh6 = sheet1.getSheets()[6];
var sh7 = sheet1.getSheets()[7]; 
var sh8 = sheet1.getSheets()[8]; 
var sh9 = sheet1.getSheets()[9]; 
var sh10 = sheet1.getSheets()[10];
var range = sh3.getRange("C2:C1000");
var arrowRange = sh1.getRange("B14");
var editClearRange = sh3.getRange("E2:E");

  var search1 = sh1.getRange("F8").getValue();
var searchBB = sh1.getRange("F5").getValue();
var SEARCH_QUERY = search1;

// Credit: https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708

function getEmails_(q) {
  var arrowRange=sh1.getRange("B14");
  var dupePreventRange = sh1.getRange("F14");
  sh0.clear();
  sh7.clear();
  editClearRange.clear();
  dupePreventRange.clear();
  sh9.getRange("A1").clear;
  arrowRange.setValue("↓");
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
            emails.push([msgs[j].getDate(), msgs[j].getPlainBody().substring(0, 49000), msgs[j].getSubject(), msgs[j].getFrom(), msgs[j].getTo()]);

        }
    }
    return emails;

}

function appendData_(sh0, array2d) {
    sh0.getRange(sh0.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(sh0, array2d);
    }

  var mycal20 = "loremipsum.com_5555554373830392d363336@resource.calendar.google.com"; // MASTER
  var cal20 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal20);
     var events20 = cal20.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var row20=sh0.getLastRow()+1;
  var range20 = sh0.getRange(row20,1,1,14);
for (var k=0;k<events20.length;k++) {
var row20=sh0.getLastRow()+1;
var details20=[[events20[k].getStartTime(), events20[k].getDescription(), events20[k].getTitle(),mycal20]];
var range20=sh0.getRange(row20,1,1,4);
range20.setValues(details20);
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
    var r1 = sh3.getRange("C2:C1000").getValues();
  var cell = sh3.getRange("D2:D1000");
  cell.setNotes(r1);
}

  var mycalSTAFF = "loremipsum.com_55555kr58832tjiach0psil3ss@group.calendar.google.com";
var STAFFcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycalSTAFF);
     var eventsSTAFF = STAFFcal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var STAFFrange = sh7.getRange(1,1,1,14);
for (var j=0;j<eventsSTAFF.length;j++) {
var rowSTAFF=j+1;
var detailsSTAFF=[[mycalSTAFF,eventsSTAFF[j].getStartTime()]];
var STAFFrange=sh7.getRange(rowSTAFF,1,1,2);
STAFFrange.setValues(detailsSTAFF);
}
    var mycalAA = "loremipsum.com_cq6ugmln55555cnlokhkl5555@group.calendar.google.com";
var AAcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycalAA);
     var eventsAA = AAcal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var AArange = sh7.getRange(1,1,1,14);
for (var k=0;k<eventsAA.length;k++) {
var rowAA=sh7.getLastRow()+1;
var detailsAA=[[mycalAA,eventsAA[k].getStartTime()]];
var AArange=sh7.getRange(rowAA,1,1,2);
AArange.setValues(detailsAA);
}
    var mycalCC = "loremipsum.com_pf50prnil2u55555vjo555555@group.calendar.google.com";
var CCcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycalCC);
     var eventsCC = CCcal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var CCrange = sh7.getRange(1,1,1,14);
for (var l=0;l<eventsCC.length;l++) {
var rowCC=sh7.getLastRow()+1;
var detailsCC=[[mycalCC, eventsCC[l].getStartTime()]];
var CCrange=sh7.getRange(rowCC,1,1,2);
CCrange.setValues(detailsCC);
}
   var mycalDD = "loremipsum.com_aer92sd55555ncf7v6i8lpt6i6j555c@group.calendar.google.com";
var DDcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycalDD);
     var eventsDD = DDcal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var DDrange = sh7.getRange(1,1,1,14);
for (var x=0;x<eventsDD.length;x++) {
var rowDD=sh7.getLastRow()+1;
var detailsDD=[[mycalDD,eventsDD[x].getStartTime()]];
var DDrange=sh7.getRange(rowDD,1,1,2);
DDrange.setValues(detailsDD);
}
   var mycalBB = "loremipsum.com_53naqi1i92h5555qor96ll555a1g@group.calendar.google.com";
var BBcal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycalBB);
     var eventsBB = BBcal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 1990 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("May 18, 2050 23:59:59 EST"), {search:(searchBB)});
var BBrange = sh7.getRange(1,1,1,14);
for (var r=0;r<eventsBB.length;r++) {
var rowBB=sh7.getLastRow()+1;
var detailsBB=[[mycalBB, eventsBB[r].getStartTime(),eventsBB[r].getDescription()]];
var BBrange=sh7.getRange(rowBB,1,1,3);
BBrange.setValues(detailsBB);


}}


  var timeStampRange = sh1.getRange("A14");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
timeStampRange.setValue(timeStamp);



function search_files() {
}
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = sheet1.getSheets()[1];
var search0 = sh1.getRange("C7").getValue();
var search5 = sh1.getRange("B3").getValue();
var searchFor = 'title contains "BB R&E"' + 'and fullText contains "' + search5 + '"';
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log (searchFor);
  Logger.log(file.getName());

}
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = sheet1.getSheets()[1];
var search0 = sh1.getRange("C7").getValue();
var search5 = sh1.getRange("B3").getValue();
var searchFor1 = 'title contains "BB R&E"' + 'and fullText contains "' + search0 + '"';
 var files1 = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor1);
while (files1.hasNext()) {
  var file1 = files1.next();
   Logger.log (searchFor1);
  Logger.log(file1.getName());

}
    var body = Logger.getLog().substring(0, 49000);
var rangeTHOMAS=sh9.getRange("A1");
rangeTHOMAS.setValue(body);



  function eventcreator1() {
  var arrowRange=sh1.getRange("B14");
    var dupePreventRange = sh1.getRange("F14");

    if (dupePreventRange.isBlank()){
          var dupePreventRange = sh1.getRange("F14");
      dupePreventRange.setValue("HELLO");
    var arrowRange=sh1.getRange("B14");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 100;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sh5.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var mycal = "loremipsum.com_55555ugmlnoaqfacn5555lokhkl55554@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0];  // First column
    var date1 = row[1];       // Second column
    var desc = row[2];
  arrowRange.setValue("↑");
    cal.createAllDayEvent(title,
     new Date(date1),
     {description: desc});
    Utilities.sleep(250);
 }  
  var startRow1 = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows1 = 100;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange1 = sh6.getRange(startRow1, 1, numRows1, 5);
  var data1 = dataRange1.getValues();
  var mycal1 = "loremipsum.com_555557kri8832tjiach0p5555sil3ss@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal1);
  for (i in data1) {
    var row1 = data1[i];
    var title1 = row1[0];  // First column
    var date2 = row1[1];       // Second column
    var desc1 = row1[2];

    cal1.createAllDayEvent(title1,
     new Date(date2),
     {description: desc1});
    Utilities.sleep(250);
  }

var startRow2 = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows2 = 450;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange2 = sh8.getRange(startRow1, 1, numRows1, 5);
  var data2 = dataRange2.getValues();
  var mycal2 = "loremipsum.com_5355555aqi1i92hl3nmqo55555lea1g@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal2);
  for (i in data2) {
    var row2 = data2[i];
    var title2 = row2[0];  // First column
    var date3 = row2[1];       // Second column
    var desc2 = row2[2];

    cal2.createAllDayEvent(title2,
     new Date(date3),
     {description: desc2}); 
    Utilities.sleep(250);
  }  
    var startRow3 = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows3 = 100;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange3 = sh10.getRange(startRow1, 1, numRows1, 5);
  var data3 = dataRange3.getValues();
  var mycal3 = "loremipsum.com_55555aqi1i92hl3nmqo55555lea1g@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal3 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal3);
  for (i in data2) {
    var row3 = data3[i];
    var title3 = row3[0];  // First column
    var date4 = row3[1];       // Second column
    var desc3 = row3[2];

    cal3.createAllDayEvent(title3,
     new Date(date4),
     {description: desc3}); 
    Utilities.sleep(250);
    var timeStampRange = sh1.getRange("A14");
  var timeStamp = new Date();
timeStampRange.setValue(timeStamp);
  }}}
```

Comment: How about creating a simplified example.  In other words a [mcve]. Provide detailed explanation and show expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through your code thoroughly for obvious reasons, but adding `saveEmails()` at the beginning of the `showPrompt` function wouldn't solve the issue?

This way every time `Search` is selected, it would be as if `RUN` was clicked too, wouldn't it?